# Permission to enable\disable devices in device manager without admin rights?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-7, group-policy, drivers

Short question: Can you use group policy to allow users to disable\enable devices without giving them full administrative rights to a machine?

More detailed: We have machines that crash on logoff\reboot when using a serial to usb adapter. The serial device was never designed to be abruptly disconnected by USB and it causes the OS to hang.

The fix was to write a program to detect logoff\reboot, block it them, disable the serial device, and then proceed to logoff. It works great with the exception that I have to grant users admin rights to the Windows machine.

Comment: I don't understand why a logoff or reboot would cause the device to abruptly disconnect. That sounds like a wonky driver to me.

Comment: There are some shocking USB-Serial drivers about.  I'd advise getting a different adapter / driver (one that works!)
FWIW I've tried to assign such permissions as you describe by group policy and was unable to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned that

Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\Load and unload device drivers

Is the GPO that determines this.

Everything is running stable now